# Wordpress restriction to the whole website

Tags: plugins

I am looking for idea or some plugin, that restricts all the wordpress website and you can unlock it only if you have a credentials. The idea is: when you write the url of the website to open a login form (which is not from the wordpress, it will be custom form with external API) and when you successfully add your username and password it will unlock the whole wordpress website. Any ideas how to make it or some plugin?

Comment: Do you mean literally lock down the entire website (header, footer - the whole presentation) -- or do you mean block content (i.e. posts) from being viewed?

Comment: Hi C C, I mean the whole website. Let me see if I can change the tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done as concisely as follows (in your theme `functions.php` or a plugin):

```
function wpse_231970_lockdown() {
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
        global $wp;

        /**
         * Redirect to login page with redirect back to current request.
         */
        wp_redirect( wp_login_url( $wp->request ) );
        exit;
    }
}

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wpse_231970_lockdown' );
```

Comment: I didn't need the code, only the idea, but thank you, I get the idea, I will modify it a little for the website need. Thank you TheDeadMedic!

Comment: Code *is* an idea!